# How do I create an mvcsitemap that displays a dynamic name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

Really struggling with this and not finding much helpful stuff on google.

I set up a sitemap, and I want some breadcrumbs such that url:

`/CatManagement/Cats/38`

displays breadcrumbs

`Cat Management > Cats > Mr. Fuzzy Wuzzy`

I don't quite understand what the sitemap node structure would be for this as the 38 is sort of a parameter of Cats.

In the dynamicNodeProvider I created I can probably grab the ID somehow and do a quick lookup to get the name, but I am not sure how to bring it all together.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Routing Basics](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Routing-Basics#programmatically-adding-the-route-parameter) in the MvcSiteMapProvider wiki. You just need to ensure that your parameter (38) is preserved from the current request, the node matching logic already takes into consideration action method parameters. That example shows how you would do that using a custom dynamic node provider, but I recommend reading the entire document as understanding it is key to making MvcSiteMapProvider work.

I have also created a more in depth look at the problem here with working demos for download: http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position